# Persistance of gcm registration id

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am doing an android application which uses gcm.I came to know that when the application is uninstalled and re installed there is no guarantee to receive the same registration id again.So what I did is while logging in I take one unique Id from application server and whenever new registration id is made I am able to replace that in application server.So what my question is, I am not using the canonical id for replacing the latest registration id in gcm server.Will it cause any problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

> On the server side, as long as the application is behaving well,
>   everything should work normally. However, if a bug in the application
>   triggers multiple registrations for the same device, it can be hard to
>   reconcile state and you might end up with duplicate messages.
>
> GCM provides a facility called "canonical registration IDs" to easily
>   recover from these situations. A canonical registration ID is defined
>   to be the ID of the last registration requested by your application.
>   This is the ID that the server should use when sending messages to the
>   device.
>
> If later on you try to send a message using a different registration
>   ID, GCM will process the request as usual, but it will include the
>   canonical registration ID in the registration_id field of the
>   response. Make sure to replace the registration ID stored in your
>   server with this canonical ID, as eventually the ID you're using will
>   stop working.

Source : http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#canonical

Comment: If you are copying your entire answer from [this page](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#canonical) word for word, the right thing to do is mark it as a quote and include a link to the source.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is basically good, though I'm not sure whether that unique Id your server generates is associated with the device or the logged in user. If it's the former, make sure you persist it on the device's external storage, so that it doesn't get lost when the app is uninstalled. If it's the latter, I'm not sure how you are handling the case of the same user logging in on multiple devices.

While your strategy is good for maintaining the current registration ID on both the device and your server, you should still handle canonical registration ID responses from Google just to be safe.